# Using the most recent cell in a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to have a formula that substracts the last cell in a column.

Example:
I fill in a value in the B column every now and then. B2 is the starting value. In C2 I want this formula to show the difference between the starting value and the most recent value. So if I fill in a value in B5 today, the formula should be

```
=B2-B5
```

But if I fill in B6 tomorrow, it should automatically change to

```
=B2-B6
```

With what formula can I do this?

Comment: Use Index and counta to return the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
=B2-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(9.99E+307,B:B))
```

Comment: Exactly! Or: `=B2-INDEX(B:B;COUNTA(B:B))` assuming `B1` is populated.

Comment: @JvdV, Thank you. I did not choose `COUNTA` for two reasons: 1. If there are intermittent blank cells then it may end up referencing wrong cell. 2. Above MATCH construct will pick up only numeric results and eliminate possibility selecting text filled cell. These are not really (explicitly) stated by OP but considered for safety.

Comment: Yes, well thought of =)

Comment: It's just numeric and B1 is the title. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

```
=$B$2-LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER($B:$B),$B:$B)
```